# Text next to the image in two colums layout

Tags: html, css, text, multiple-columns

I am trying to create contact blocks with rounded image on the left and contact details on the right. Something like this:

Contact block:

[image: Contact block]

It is working fine with one column layout, but when I am trying to create two columns then the text moves below the picture.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div Id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobile-device/512/man-body-person-blue-round-512.png" alt="" width=200px id="pic">
            <div class="details">
              <p id="p1">John Doe</p>
              <p id="p2"><a href="www.google.pl">More information</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div Id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobile-device/512/man-body-person-blue-round-512.png" alt="" width=200px id="pic">
            <div class="details">
              <p id="p1">John Doe</p>
              <p id="p2"><a href="www.google.pl">More information</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
  #wrapper ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  #wrapper ul li {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #wrapper ul li img {
    float: left;
  }
  
  #wrapper ul li .details {
    float: left;
    padding: 70px 0 0 20px;
    width: 75%;
  }
  
  #p1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  #p2 {
    line-height: 0px;
  }
  
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
</style>
```

Could you please help me to fix it? Can you also tell me how to create a round photo when I link to a rectangular one?

Comment: Can you try with flex layout.

Comment: @Asutosh, I tried now but with the same result. However, I don't have much experience, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/opeg32hL/7/

```css
 #wrapper ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: auto;
   width: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
 }

 #wrapper ul li {
   padding: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
 }

 #wrapper ul li img {
   float: left;
 }

 #wrapper ul li .details {

   padding: 70px 0 0 20px;
   width: 75%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 #p1 {
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
 }


 .column {
   float: left;
   flex-basis: 50%;
   flex-shrink:1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div Id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobile-device/512/man-body-person-blue-round-512.png" alt="" width=200px id="pic">
            <div class="details">
              <p id="p1">John Doe</p>
              <p id="p2"><a href="www.google.pl">More information</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div Id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobile-device/512/man-body-person-blue-round-512.png" alt="" width=200px id="pic">
            <div class="details">
              <p id="p1">John Doe</p>
              <p id="p2"><a href="www.google.pl">More information</a></p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Asutosh, one more question to this solution. How can I move the text below the photo for smaller screens? I want to use @media screen and (max-width: 600px).

Comment: try the below fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/kcozp4ny/6/

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I cannot achive my goal. I've been analyzing the code for a few hours and I'm missing something. I'm sending my current code. What should I change? https://jsfiddle.net/pawciok/8ef5Lkmc/

Comment: instead of .li at the bottom style put only li